# Casbah - getAsOrElse not working on Option values

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I have the following code:

```
new Room(
  dbObject.get("_id").get.toString,
  List[User]() ,
  List[Message](),
  dbObject.getAs[Date]("creation").get,
  //dbObject.getAsOrElse[Option[Date]]("expires", None),
  if(dbObject.containsField("expires")) 
    Some(dbObject.getAs[Date]("expires").get) 
  else 
    None,
  List[String]())
```

I would like to know what i'm doing wrong on use getAsOrElse because if i use the commented line, i'll never get the value from field **expires**. To fix it, i need to  implement that if sentence to get the value.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `getAs[T]` returns Option[T] you can just use that eg:

```
dbObject.getAs[Date]("expires")
```

Will return `Some(dateValue)` if the expires field is of a `Date` or it will return `None` if expires field doesn't exist *or* if the expires field isn't castable to a `Date`.

Comment: That fix it for you @placplacboom?